# How to install postman in windows server 2007 SP2 (windows vista)

Tags: postman, windows-vista

I need to install postman on an old windows 2007 SP2.
I am not even sure if it is actually 2007, but here is the screenshot of system properties
[image]

Why I need postman?
Because there is another web service that is only accessible through this old windows, and the support team of the mentioned service do not want to cooperate through other means such as pure http requests/responses, and they want me to use postman.

I am really stuck at this for a long time.
I tried to search for a port-forwarding software but couldn't find one :(

Edit: after a simple search, I found that the version is 6.0.6002 (Windows Vista)

Comment: Have you tried installing it? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: I can't install it, it does not open. When I click it shows nothing (Edited)

Comment: wait a sec, to make sure I did.. Ok the installer won't open

Answer (score 0):

Postman did not work for me too on a Windows Server 2007 SP2. As an option you can install SoapUI 5.5.0 on your server. SoapUI supports SOAP and REST services.